# How can I un-register then re-register NICs without rebooting?

Tags: networking, devices

I have an Ubuntu VM that's using iptables to forward packets.  After each reboot, the maximum throughput of the forwarding is significantly different, so I'm trying to narrow down which step is causing this.  I'm wondering if it's about the order that NICs are added, or something else having to do with initializing them on boot.

How can I remove an interface and add it again?  Note that I've tried bringing the interface down and back up, but that doesn't change the performance, so I'm looking for something more radical.

Comment: I think your question should instead be "How do i debug maximum throughput issues" instead...  if you aren't sure where in the process the problem is introduced you might want to start from the absolute step 1

Comment: rmmod and modprobe, maybe?

Comment: Thanks @davidbaumann, that's what I was looking for!  If you want to turn your comment into an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

davidbaumann is right: `rmmod` and `modprobe`.  Thanks for the tip!

For the record:

`sudo service networking restart` is broken:

```
$ sudo service networking stop
stop: Unknown instance:
```

And `ifconfig` confirms that all interfaces and still up and running.

Similarly, `/etc/init.d/networking stop` leaves all the interfaces up, according to `ifconfig`.

The "offical" way to bring down an interface is `ip link set eth0 down`, but the interface still shows up in the output of `ifconfig -a`.

But `rmmod` removes it, it doesn't even show up in `ifconfig -a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can unload the driver, and then reload, with rmmod and modproble.
This will unload and then load the kernel module, for your ethernet adapter.

For virtual box, this is `e1000`

```
# rmmod e1000
# ifconfig
lo    Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
      inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
      inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
      RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
      RX bytes:240 (240.0 B)  TX bytes:240 (240.0 B)
# modprobe e1000
# ifconfig
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 08:00:27:48:89:50  
      inet Adresse:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
      inet6-Adresse: fe80::a00:27ff:fe48:8950/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
      RX bytes:780 (780.0 B)  TX bytes:1118 (1.0 KiB)

lo    Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
      inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
      inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
      RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
      RX bytes:240 (240.0 B)  TX bytes:240 (240.0 B)
```